# Add new column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to postgresql. I have a table with `first_names` and `last_names`. I want to add a column called `full_name` in the table (which would add the `first_name` and `last_name`). To add a column I used the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE actor ADD COLUMN full_name varchar(50);
```

To concatenate the the column, I can use the formula:

```
CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) from actor
```

But I do not know as how to add the concat values to my new `full_name` column. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the column:

```
update actor
    set full_name = CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name);
```